# Execution Transcript missing with new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8

Tags: google-apps-script, v8, google-apps-script-editor

When using the Google Apps Script editor and using the new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8, the Execution Transcript under View is gone.  I'm wondering, where did it go?  Has it been replaced by something?  Is it gone for good?

I've tried all sorts of searches and forums, but unbelievably, I seem to be the only one who's noticed this.  I find the Execution Transcript quite useful so I hope there is some kind of replacement if it is gone.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The new runtime doesn't include a feature that pairs exactly with what is done by the Executions Transcript. If you need to log the duration of an specific part of your code you might use `console.time(label)` / `console.timeEnd(label)`.

---

This was officially launched in February 5, 2020. According to the official docs, this is by design.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#ui_changes_for_logging

> #### UI changes for executions
>
> The location of execution transcripts has changed under V8. If your script uses the Rhino runtime, you can find execution transcripts for scripts selecting the View > Execution Transcript menu in the Apps Script editor. This opens an Execution transcript dialog that lists the most recent execution transcript, which lists calls to Apps Script services along with associated timestamps.
>
> If your script uses the V8 runtime, execution transcripts are no longer available. Instead you can view the execution history in the Apps Script dashboard by selecting View > Executions in the Apps Script editor. This opens the Executions panel for the script project. From here you can select an execution to see Stackdriver logs associated with it. Unlike execution transcripts in Rhino, the Executions panel can show you an execution history from multiple runs of your script (instead of only the most recent execution).

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#february_5_2020

Comment: Is there a setup to receive similar information? (IDE, etc.)

Comment: @TamLe From the quoted text in the answer "Instead you can view the execution history in the Apps Script dashboard by selecting View > Executions in the Apps Script editor."

Comment: They are not the same. The execution list don't have details for each line of code executed.

Comment: In this new design, you cannot see time for each method.

Answer (score 1):

Please Disabled the V8 runtime, execution transcripts are no longer available. You can disabled from Script Editor

***Script Editor***

[image]

***Disable Menu***

[image]

Comment: Is there a setup to receive similar information? (IDE, etc.)